# Dropbox sync api large video file upload

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using Dropbox sync api for downloading text file and upload video file from/to dropbox via my ios application.

I am struggling while uploading heavy video file.While i am uploading video file of duration 15 to 20 minutes its uploaded correctly, but if the duration is more than 25 minutes
then it gets memory waring and app crashes.

I am using this code on upload button action

```
DBPath *paths=[[DBPath root] childPath:[self.allVideoArray objectAtIndex:Selectedvideo]];
DBFile *createfile=[filesystem createFile:paths error:nil];
NSData  *data=[[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:self.path];
[createfile writeData:data error:nil];     
[data relese];
```

Please some body way me out from this problem. Any help should be appreciable, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sync API seems to not allow video upload for me. It says file type not allowed. how did you get it working with the Sync api?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you create an `NSData` instance containing the entire file. If the file is too big to fit into memory your app will crash. There are better ways to write large files to a `DBFile`.

Since you have a path to the local file you could do:

```
DBPath *paths=[[DBPath root] childPath:[self.allVideoArray objectAtIndex:Selectedvideo]];
DBFile *createfile=[filesystem createFile:paths error:nil];
[createFile writeContentsOfFile:self.path shouldSteal:NO error:nil];
```

Another option would be to read the file at `self.path` in smaller chunks and use `DBFile appendData:error:`.

Side note - you really need to check return values to make sure these calls are working or not and make use of the `error` parameter to log the cause of the problem (if any).

Comment: @ rmaddy thanks for your reply by using your code it avoids crash but small video file is uploaded successfully. But in case of heavy video it is showing in drop box but also showing 0 bytes.

Comment: Are you checking the return value of `writeContentsOfFile:shouldSteal:error:`? If it returns `NO` then check the error.

Comment: @ rmaddy i have check it returns YES, but i saw in debugger console it printed  [WARNING] ERR: DROPBOX_ERROR_NOTFOUND: sync.hpp:282: p(/c7.mov) does not exist

Comment: Then your path to the file isn't valid.

Comment: paths are like this, /var/mobile/Applications/DE7B9C54-EA0E-4F0F-BCAF-868D4A943968/Documents/ughu.MOV. and also small video are uploaded.